# AngularJS - Controller or function to split a phone number

Tags: angularjs, split, substring

I want to use the following code snippet to modify a phone number into angularJS.

```
var input = "0123456789";
var area = input.substring(0, 3);
var country = input.substring(3, 10);
```

I don't know if create a controller or a function into a existent controller.

I made a controller, but I don't know if it has sense

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('Spliptter', Spliptter);

function Spliptter($scope){
  var input = $scope.phoneNumber.number; //number took from a form field
  var area = input.substring(0, 3);
  var country = input.substring(3, 10);

  $scope.area: area,
  $scope.country: country,
}
```

Thanks ind advance!

Answer (score 1):

1. Controller is not meant to put the business logic or a common logic which everywhere can be used. Because Controller can not be injected as a dependency.
2. Angular has provided Service or Factory which is used to put the business logic and can be injected everywhere.

I would recommend the below solution:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('Spliptter', Spliptter)
.service('SplitService', SplitService);

function Spliptter($scope, SplitService){
  var result = SplitService.phoeNoSplit($scope.phoneNumber.number);

  $scope.area: result['area'];
  $scope.country: result['country'];
}

function SplitService() {
   this.phoeNoSplit = function(phoneNumber) {
     var area = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3);
     var country = phoneNumber.substring(3, 10); 

     return {
       'area': area,
       'country': country
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: In the line 7 and 8, the code editor and the console, gives me an error. I change the ':' for '=' but I can not opportunity for test this, because my backend is down. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh yaa typo mistake. Replace ":" with "=" there.                                              $scope.area = result['area'];                                                   $scope.country = result['country'];

Comment: It not worked, I think. I want to use $scope.area and the $scope.country to fill a form but when I send it  don't take the data stored there.
Example $ScopePhone: $scope.country,
               $ScopeLongDistance: $scope.area

Comment: Bansai: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19769/angular-js-i-want-send-data-stored-on-a-serivice

Comment: I have answered on your above link.